# C# array include symbol

Tags: c#

I have list of items:

```
Apple\3
Orange\8
Kivi\9
```

I wish to add these items in C # array:

```
string[] fruit={"Apple\3","Orange\8","Kivi\9"};
```

But it return me error as the backslash not acceptable ("\"), by the way the backslash is a must to include, anyone have ideas?

Comment: You need to either escape your backslash `"Apple\\3"` or use verbatim strings `@"Apple\3"`. Look up escape characters if you want to know why.

Answer (score 2):

Backslash is normally being interpreted by C# as *there is going to be a command following*... such as `\n` for linebreaking.

If you need the backslash in your string, you simply have to add another backslash.

```
Apple\\3
Orange\\8
Kivi\\9
```

Answer (score 0):

\ signals the beginning of an escape sequence, which tells it to not read what immediately follows it in a string literally.

so if you wanted to include the character " in a string, you can use \" to let it know that you are not ending the string. if you wanted to include \ in a string you use \\ . there are also sequences that you can use to do something, like to change text color in terminal.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence

also fun fact, you can use \ in discord also, if you are trying to write some math like 5 * 6 * 7, it would normally interpret the * 6 * to mean that it should be in bold. instead, you can write 5 \* 6 \* 7 and it will display properly! also apparently this is true for stackoverflow as well haha

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` is escape charter and cannot be interpreted and treated as special character. This can be fixed by adding one more backslash after escape character `\\` like this

```
string[] fruit= {"Apple\\3","Orange\\8","Kivi\\9"};
```

or adding `@` before string like this

```
string[] fruit= {@"Apple\3",@"Orange\8",@"Kivi\9"};
```